# iPhone UITableView populateing from connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have been trying for hours to figure this out. I have some JSON from a NSURLConnection. This is working fine and I have parsed it into an array. But I can't seem to get the array out of the connectionDidFinishLoading method. I an am getting (null) in the UITableViewCell method. I am assuming this is a scope of retain issue, but I am so new to ObjC I am not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

```m
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSDictionary *results = [json objectWithString:responseString];

self.dataArray = [results objectForKey:@"data"];

NSMutableArray *tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

for (NSString *element in dataArray) {
    //NSLog(@"%@", [element objectForKey:@"name"]);
    NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[element objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [tableArray addObject:tmpString];
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
//cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", tableArray);
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get rid of the `[connection release]` in the 2nd line. The `connection` object comes in autoreleased, so this could cause crashes.
2. It looks like you've got a property named `tableArray`? If so, you're redeclaring the name in this method (you should have gotten a compiler warning).

On second thought, here's how the 2nd 1/2 of the method should look:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

for (NSString *element in dataArray) {
    [tmpArray addObject:[element objectForKey:@"name"]];
}

self.tableArray = tmpArray;
[tmpArray release];
```

Comment: kubi.
I tried this way and I am still getting null in UITableVIewCell method? But I get the right values in connectionDidFinishLoading. It's still getting stuck in there...
Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: I did notice this:
2010-02-06 13:38:07.907 Courses[34368:207] (null)
2010-02-06 13:38:07.908 Courses[34368:207] (null)
2010-02-06 13:38:07.910 Courses[34368:207] (null)
2010-02-06 13:38:07.952 Courses[34368:207] (
    "My Golf Course",
    "Glen Annie",
    "Alisal Ranch",
    "Santa Barbara Golf Club",
    "Rancho San Marcos"
)
The UITableViewCell seems to be loading before the connectionDidFinishLoading. So the values don't exist yet...

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
After taking kubi and st3fan's advice with `self.tableArray` I found I had to reload the tableView with `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you! ps. you should mark one of our answers correct.

Answer (score 0):

In `connectionDidFinishLoading:` you use declare `tableArray` as a local variable. Therefore it will never be assigned to `self.tableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it reloading the table.

I inserted this line at the end of connectionDidFinishLoading function

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and it works.